# Stack and Heap addresses in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I did a lot of research about memory allocation in Objective-C and I've read a lot of articles and blogs about this stuff but I stil have some unclear moments. I know that object types stores in heap and primitive types in stack, but may you please explain to me a little bit more about listed example:

```
NSObject *obj;

NSLog(@"%p", obj); //prints 0x0 which means address in stack ?
NSLog(@"%p", &obj); //prints 0x7ffee427bf68 which means address in heap ?

obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%p", obj); //prints 0x6000000119b0 which means address in stack ?
NSLog(@"%p", &obj); //prints 0x7ffee427bf68 which means address in heap ?
```

Same for the primitive type:

```
int value = 23;

NSLog(@"%p", value); //prints 0x17 - is that a stack address ?
NSLog(@"%p", &value); //prints 0x7ffeea19bf6c - is that a stack address too ?
```

Comment: 0x17 it's 23 in HEX. it's a value, not address.

Comment: Really...I did not realise it before for primitive types. Thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever variable which is local to block will be store in stack memory even if it is pointer but if you have use pointer to store address and that address is from dynamic memeory than that will be stored in heap memory for example:

```
Func()
{
int *a ;    
int b;   --stack memory
a = malloc (sizeof(int));    
Printf &a;-----this will be stack memory pointer and will be store in stack memory.   
Print a;-----this will point to address which is allocate by heap this will be store in heap memory.   

}
```